# pdo select specific row once

Tags: php, pdo

I want to return Title only once and then a list of all users with correct n_id.

I have such table:

```
| N_ID |  USER | TITLE  |
|------|-------|--------|
| 1    | User1 | Title1 |
| 1    | User2 | Title1 |
| 1    | User3 | Title1 |
| 2    | User3 | Title5 |
```

My code so far:

```
$sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM n_list WHERE n_id = :id");
$sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
$sql->execute();
while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo 'Title: '.$rows["title"].' <br></br>';
echo $rows["user"];
}
```

Currently it gives me this:

```
Title: Title1
User1
Title: Title1
User2
Title: Title1
User3
```

I need this as a result:

```
Title: Title1
User1
User2
User3
```

How do I get the title row before while loop?
Do I add another fetch there or I add another query?

I am new to pdo so sorry if the solution looks obvious to you!

Comment: GROUP BY or DISTINCT is your friend

Comment: With in your loop save the N_ID. If the N_ID changes print the title out.

Comment: @bub Group by gives me only one result. Distinct does not work and prints the same as in my example.

Comment: Have you tried GROUP BY title?

Comment: @JasonK I am getting n_id from website url so it should only print the title to that specific n_id.

Comment: @bub Yes, I tried that. Tried by the id and by the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeting a flag to know the title has printed should work.

```
$sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM n_list WHERE n_id = :id");
$sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
$sql->execute();

$flagtitle = 0;

while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
  if($flagtitle == 0){
    echo 'Title: '.$rows["title"].' <br>';
    $flagtitle = 1;
  }
  echo $rows["user"].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you!
You have some errors in your code though.
$flagtitle = 1' should be $flagtitle = 1;